# change the position of the beamer page numbering

Tags: beamer, header-footer, page-numbering, templates, footer

I used `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]` in my beamer template but it destroys my original foot line.

So, upon my search I found the following to add before the `\begin{document}`. It is what I want but just need to have that aligned left. Currently, it is in the middle. Any help on how to solve this?

`\expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshorttitle\expandafter{% \insertshorttitle\hfill% \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}`

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of your code. Don't make us guess what other templates and settings you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the `footline` using three `beamercolorbox`.

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=<width>,
                       ht=<height>,
                       dp=<depth>,
                       <right, left  or center>,
                       rightskip=<space>, 
                       leftskip =<space>
                      ]{fg=<color name>, 
                        bg=<color name>}
```

The three widths must add up to `1\paperwidth`.

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.40\paperwidth,ht=6ex,dp=2.5ex,
                               left,leftskip=2.5ex]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle{}\newline%
            \insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}%   
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.20\paperwidth,ht=6ex,dp=2.5ex,
                               center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertframenumber{} / %
            \inserttotalframenumber
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.40\paperwidth,ht=6ex,dp=2.5ex,
                               right,rightskip=2ex]{title in head/foot}%
          \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}       
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
}
```

[image: a]